# Why is tomcat saying initialization failed for eclipse scout project

Tags: java, eclipse

After setting up apache tomcat and opening manager app, then uploading the 2 war files from my eclipse scout project, I type in my password and when i hit login it loads to the page but it says initialization failed and wont show anything. the title of my application shows on the same page of the error, but the actual application wont load. is there something i need to add in my project?

Comment: Do the tomcat log files show any errors?

Comment: mba12 - nope they build error free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i changed the port in one of the tomcat config files to 9999 when eclipse scouts code only expects 8080 so all i did was keep the port at 8080.

Comment: You could have changed the port in the scout module [...]ui.html.app.war under src/main/resources config.properties file. 

The property scout.server.url is the one that had to be adapted.